# Using Intel compiler on KVM guests

Tags: compiler-construction, cpu, virtualization, intel, kvm

I'm using KVM guests and will compile apache by intel compiler for high performance.
Is it good idea to use intel compiler on virtual machines ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the virtual machines exposes the system architecture to the guest OS.

Intel compilers tend to generate code that works well for the architecture you're building on, and since your VM will probably hide all the details that the compilers use to generate good code, it may not work as you expect. You may get bad performance, or it might even simply fail to build.

Have you tried yet?

Comment: Yes, I could compiled apache by Intel comiler, but couldn't get good performance. I'll try again ! (compile option may be not good.)